# Unable to parse the csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am basically trying to read the csv file from s3 location using dynamic frame. And I have also made a created a table using crawler for the same csv file.

read a CSV file from an S3 location from dynamic frame options

The error I am getting is:
An error occurred while calling o80.schema. Unable to parse file: file_name.csv

I have also tried getting the encoding used for the file: "ISO-8859-1". and also tried using it.

and read a CSV file from an S3 location from dynamic frame options

But it also didn't work. So when removed schema calling part from above code, still getting error:

## error

An error occurred while calling o81.toDF. Unable to parse file: file_name.csv

## Actual error message:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.schema.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 25, 172.36.93.177, executor 2): com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FatalException: Unable to parse file: file.csv

What is the issue here?

```py
# read a CSV file from an S3 location from dynamic frame options
csv_dynamicframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    "s3",
    connection_options = {
        "paths": [root_path]
        },
    format = "csv",
    format_options = {
        'withHeader': True,
        "quoteChar": -1, 
        "separator": ",",
        'encoding': 'Windows-1252'
        },
    transformation_ctx = "csv_dynamicframe",
    schema=dynamic_frame_catalog.schema()
)
```

Comment: Since you have the file(s) appeared as a table in Glue data catalog, you can use `csv_dynamicframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = db_name, table_name = tbl_name)` directly.